# MongoDB C# query execution location

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a few mongo queries.

```
var threads = postCollection.AsQueryable<PostMongoEntity>()
            .Select(w => w.ThreadId);

var entities = threadCollection.AsQueryable<ThreadMongoEntity>()
            .Where(e => e.ThreadId.In(threads))
            .OrderBy(e => e.Time)
            .Skip(page * ThreadPageSize)
            .Take(ThreadPageSize);
```

The first query finds all threads ids from a posts collection, the second gets all threads with that id. I wanted to know if this will do everything on the actual database. This isn't the complete query, but most of the important stuff is here. The part I'm woried about is `Where(e => e.ThreadId.In(threads))`. Will it send the thread list to the database or will it get all threads and do filtering locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will send the list of threadIds to MongoDB. IT will NOT pull all the records back and do the filtering locally. I assume this is what you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from type compatibility looks legal. `threads` is `IQueryable` that implements `IEnumerable`, while operation `In` accept exactly IEnumerable (http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.9.2/)

*Sorry* just look attentively at your question
<s>But!
obviously you need use long (or what type is dedicated for Id in PostMongoEntity). So it is became legal only if `In` accept IEnumerable of primitive types instead of entities.</s>

P.S. This method have some restriction on number of PostMongoEntity keys - cannot quickly find exact reference.